# Using implementation of Map interface instead of List interface to store data in BaseAdapter

Tags: java, android

I want to use one of the implementations of the Map interface instead of implementing the ArrayList to store data in BaseAdapter. I'm looking for the best way to get values from Map by index. Creating lists from map when i have index seem to be highly not efficient.

```
@Override
public Object getItem(int position) {
// TODO Auto-generated method stub
List<Map.Entry<String, String>> 
list = new LinkedList<Map.Entry<String,String>>(this.countries.entrySet());
return list.get(position);
}
```

Any suggestion how to do it in right way?

Thanks in advanace.

Comment: Why don't you use better a List<Pair<String,String>> instead of a map?

Comment: I want to save the access to the values of map by key in activity that have instance of BaseAdapter. Therefore I pass the Map in BaseAdapter constructor

Comment: But... EntrySet is a Set (no order). You can't expect any kind of order in a list built form a set.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For performance, you need to keep `ArrayList` with values of your `Map` in your adapter separately :

```
// Map<String, String> countries;
ArrayList<String> countryList = new ArrayList<String>(countries.values());
```

You will also need to update the list every time your map changes and you are about to call `notifyDataSetChanged()`

This way, you get optimal O(1) performance (as it should be) for your getItem() :

```
@Override
public Object getItem(int position) {
    return position < countryList.size() ? countryList(position) : null;
}
```

and don't forget to return correct value in getCount() :

```
@Override
public Object getCount() {
    return countryList.size();
}
```

Note, there will be no guarantee on how values of your list (coming from the map) will be ordered, so you may want to sort them as well.

Comment: I was struggling how to solve the problem with the communication between map and list. And how to provide the list with the same elements that are added to the map. And I figured out that the map should provide an interface to notify that new item has just appear the map. This interface would be implemented by the BaseAdapter.